# C++ standard requirements to templates that are not instantiated

Tags: c++, templates, template-instantiation

So I tried to compile the code below and it failed (as expected):

```
1.cpp: In function ‘int foo()’:
1.cpp:3:5: error: ‘some’ was not declared in this scope
     some ill-formed code
     ^
```

But if I remove this line the compiler compiles it without any errors (also expected as it is unknown whether the `T` type has `random_name()` method or not).

It seems that diagnostic for templates that are not used (not instantiated) is implementation defined to some extent. But perhaps the standard has some requirements for such cases. For example would it conform to the standard to compile the code below without any errors?

I tried to search for the answer on the site but could not find any related questions.

```
template <class T>
int foo() {
    some ill-formed code
    return T::random_name();
}

template <>
int foo<int>() { return 0; }

int main() {
    return foo<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quality of implementation issue, it is ill-formed but if it is not instantiated no diagnostic is required as per [[temp.res#8.1]p](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1):

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.
>   [ Note: Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked in this way.
>   — end note
>    ]
>   The **program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if**:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or

and we can see [from this live godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/lIC8Kx) MSVC does not diagnose this case. This is because [MSVC is not using two-phase lookup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/) but using `/permissive-` changes this. clang even has an [MSVC compatibility mode to emulate this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html) using `-fdelayed-template-parsing`.

We can see [from this live godbolt using these two options](https://godbolt.org/z/YP54vN) clang no longer produces a diagnostic but MSVC does.

Comment: That rule is quite confusing. `template<class T> SomeParticularError { static_assert(always_false<T>::value); };` is very common, but this rule seems to apply. That is, if `SomeParticularError` is not actually instantiated, this is ill-formed, NDR.

Comment: @liliscent - That rule doesn't apply. `alwsys_false` may still have a specialization producing a true value. It's a non-deduced context for a reason.

Comment: @StoryTeller If this is true, then the **"and the template is not instantiated"** part seems to be redundant, since a template will never be instantiated at its definition. In my previous comment, I thought that sentence means "it's not instantiated during the whole translation unit", if it refers to the whole TU, compiler has all the knowledge to determine whether there are other specializations of `always_false`.

Comment: @liliscent - It's not redundant. The point here is that one can tell the construct is ill-formed without instantiating the template. But with `always_false` one can never tell a specialization won't exist.

Comment: @StoryTeller I believe you're right. I was just thinking the wording could've been more clear, since the whole section [temp.res]/8 is talking about ill-formedness at a template's definition, *not instantiated* is implied from the context of that section.

Answer (score 0):

Names inside a function `template` are either *dependent*, i.e., the entity depends on the `template` parameters in some form, or they are *independent*, i.e., there is no indication that it depends on a `template` parameter. Independent names are looked up when the function `template` is defined. Dependent names are looked up during `template` instantiation, i.e., at the name doesn’t need to be defined when the function `template` is defined. Failure to look-up a name is an error. The details of this process are a bit more involved and fill most of the chapter on `template`s.

In your case `some` is an independent name while the `T::` qualification makes `random_name` a dependent name.

Comment: `some ill-formed` is a syntax error though, so I don't think it gets so far as dependent name analysis